# c++ mysql Connector select id from string

Tags: c++, mysql

i am trying to select ID from table where IP_Address = [string]

i will get the ip address from another function

```
    std::string GetIP(){
    return IP;
    }

  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;
  sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1.:3306", "root", "password");
  con->setSchema("Test");
stmt = con->createStatement();
string GETI = "84.54.584.6"; // will be GetIP()
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM IPs Where IP_Address = '"+ GETI +"'");
while (res->next()) {
cout << "id = " << res->getInt(1); 
}
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

i dont get any error in error list of visual studio

but when i run the application it dont display value and application crash

when i try

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM IPs Where IP_Address = '84.54.584.6'");
```

i get it working fine

Comment: did you try to debug application? Which line causing the crash?

Comment: i think the line which had select :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = stmt->executeQuery(std::string("SELECT ID FROM IPs Where IP_Address = '"+ GETI +'\'').c_str());
```